# Passing "#" hash symbol in request parameter of url not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am hitting a struts action using AJAX, everything is fine but there is problem with Firefox , when i am passing the parameter in URL as a request parameter and if that parameter, contains hash(#) symbol in the end, then firefox strips everything after that symbol and send that parameter to action without it.

For example, if im passing test123#abcd in Firefox, then i am getting only test123 in action class as opposed to test123#abcd which is undesirable for my requirement.For IE it is working perfectly.Is there any way by which i can extract the full parameter including the # symbol in Firefox.

please let me know if i need to post the java action code also,thanks.

JS snippet

```
var valuePassword=test123#abcd;

    var url = "/test/ChangePwdAjax.do?newPass="+valuePassword;
            var xmlHTTP = getXMLHTTPRequest();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use

```
var url = "/test/ChangePwdAjax.do?newPass="+ encodeURIComponent(valuePassword);
```

This will encode your `valuePassword` to a valid URL component which can be passed as a query string in URLs

And on the other side you should use `decodeURIComponent` to get the value from encoded string

```
var value = decodeURIComponent(valuePasswordPassed);
```

To know more about this [Go here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: The reason is that yo have to encode your data. A hash (#) isn't valid here, the hash, and everything that follows, should never leave your browser

Comment: Personally I'd link to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead of w3schools (which have a tendency to produce sub-par documentation).

Comment: Thankyou all, it works, earlier i was limited by my thought process since in IE it was working fine.I also was wondering why both browsers were behaving differently, i agree that the URL query string must be encoded. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you change data you have to do a http POST request. Not a GET request. This will automatically solve your problem without having to encode your password.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/test/ChangePwdAjax.do", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("newPass=" + valuePassword);
```

Comment: I tried that by changing xmlHTTP.open("GET",url,true); to xmlHTTP.open("POST",url,true); but its the same.not sure if im doing it correctly.But encoding solved my purpose.Thanks.

Comment: @user1697113 The values shouldn't be in the url but in the body. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Surely worth mentioning that passing a password as a URL parameter is a terrible idea. A passer-by can see your new password in your browser's address bar.  And anyone in the future can find the password in your browsing history.

-mobailey