# Allow to send special characher in the url while doing Post request from UI side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api, special-characters

I was trying to send below special character (**!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++***) in the request url. It is a **POST** request.  It is not allowing to send all the sepecial characher in the query string but It takes only first two special characters of the entry.

How can we send all the special character in the request url.

var reason = **"!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++*)(*&^%$#@!!@#$%^&*()*++*";**

var id = **123**;

**$http.post(serviceBaseUrl + 'abc/abc?id=' + id + '&reason=' + reason);**

**Request URL:** http://localhost:8080/abc/abc/abc/abc?id=123&reason=**!@**

Kindly suggest me how to achive this.

Thank you

Comment: You need to remove "#" from the parameter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683131/10213537. What's actually happening is the "!@" are being passed into the query parameters correctly, but everything beyond the "#" is being interpreted as an HTML id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, what it looks like you need to do is use the `encodeURIComponent` method, so what you're code would be is

```
$http.post(serviceBaseUrl + 'abc/abc?id=' + id + '&reason=' + encodeURIComponent(reason));
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228872/10213537